# self.navigationItem.titleView cutting off UIBarButtonItem after rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I use a `self.navigationItem.titleView` and I set two UIButtons as the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` in the `UINavigationBar`. I have achieved this in my navigationBar like so [image]

Whenever I rotate the view controller landscape and then back, the uibarbutton item gets cut off like so
[image]

The code I use to set the `titleView` is this:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44)];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];
titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.text = self.tabTitle;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I wonder if if any of you know how to fix this.

Comment: How did you add the tool bar to the navigation bar?

Comment: oh wait i used the UIToolbar before but now it is different. The code i use right now is http://pastie.org/5499759